# Xpages - Custom property using method binding option is not showing the content

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a custom control with around 20 custom properties. However, some of these properties need to contain code logic. This is fine, as I create the property as Type: javax.faces.el.MethodBinding and Editor: Method Binding Editor which works fine.

However, once I close the editor, click somewhere else, then click back to the custom properties of my custom control, the code has disappeared. If I look at the source code however, the logic is visible. Its a little frustrating, as whenever I want to use the editor, I need to copy my code from the source and paste back into the editor (to help with formatting, showing errors as I type etc)

Has anyone else come across this and know how to fix it, or is this just another quirk of designer?

**This image shows the empty property**
[image]

**This image shows the property has logic in the source code**
[image]

Comment: Why did you post this question six times?

Comment: @Cataklysim I didn't realise it had posted so many times, but I posted the question just before Stack went down for maintenance earlier today so I assume its something to do with that. I will delete the other questions. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Domino Designer that you should report to IBM/HCL by opening a support ticket at https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/